# What are the threads with empty stack on tomcat 8.0 JVM?

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

I am diagnosing an unresponsive tomcat 8.0_29 instance (jdk1.8_93). Some threads are blocked but there are a lot of RUNNABLE threads (hundreds) with empty stacktrace.
Tomcat is running behind Apache http on different virtual machine.
Cennector config is as follows:
`

```
    <Connector port="8443"
     protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
     SSLEnabled="true" secure="true" enableLookups="false"
     disableUploadTimeout="true"
     keystoreFile="${catalina.home}/conf/server.jks"
     keystorePass="xxxxxx"
     acceptCount="100" maxThreads="25" scheme="https"
     clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLSv1.2"/>


<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" 
    acceptorThreadCount="2" maxThreads="300" acceptCount="200" minSpareThreads="20"
    connectionTimeout="180000" keepAliveTimeout="180000" URIEncoding="ISO-8859-1" /> `
```

SSL termination is made by Apache son only calls through AJP reach Tomcat

`Thread-41827 - priority:5 - threadId:0x00007f44e932f800 - nativeId:0xd7d - state:RUNNABLE
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE`

Many of them are named 'thread-$id', the rest are 'HandshakeCompletedNotify-Thread'

`HandshakeCompletedNotify-Thread - priority:5 - threadId:0x00007f44fc841000 - nativeId:0x7565 - state:RUNNABLE
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE`

What are those threads?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Seems, this has something to do with TLS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408767/ssl-handshake-problems

Comment: thanks @Henry i've added more info. tomcat is behind apache http and ssl is managed by the latter

Comment: @problems That is an old problem (java 5/6), I don't think this is the same issue